# Jackson json file to list of objects, can not instantiate value of type MyObj from String value

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have successfully created JSON file from my List, I have to read it again into list but exception **can not instantiate value of type MyObj from String value** occurrs.

Here is my json file, it is an array of json objects.

```
"[ {\r\n  \"id\" : 103,\r\n  \"productId\" : 6,\r\n  \"quantity\" : 1,\r\n  \"orderId\" : 10195,\r\n  \"clerksId\" : [ 1, 2, 6 ],\r\n  \"name\" : \"keyboard\",\r\n  \"description\" : \"-\",\r\n  \"dateOfOrder\" : \"2021-02-08\",\r\n  \"note\" : \"\",\r\n  \"price\" : 62.2\r\n} ]"
```

And here is my approach to converting it to the list of objects.

```
                    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                     mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
                    
                    
                    try(InputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream("src/resources/my_json.json")) {
                        List<MyObj> list = mapper.readValue(fileStream, new
                                  TypeReference<List<MyObj>>() { });
                        System.out.println(list);
                    }
```

MyObj has all the matching properties, both default no arg ctor and all the set methods.

Edit:
Here is the method I am using to create my .json file.

```
public static <T> String parseAndWrite(List<T> listToParse, String outputFile) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

        String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(listToParse);

        // Create output file.
        StringBuilder filePath = new StringBuilder();
        filePath.append("src/resources/").append(outputFile).append(".json");
        try {
            objectMapper.writeValue(Paths.get(filePath.toString()).toFile(), json);

            return json;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: does MyObj have setters for all properties? does it have a default no args constructor?

Comment: Yes it does, both default no arg ctor and all mutators.

Comment: Can you try arraylist instead of list when instantiating TypeReference?

Comment: I tried it, still the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

### MyObj.java

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class MyObj {
  public MyObj() {}

  private int id;
  private int productId;
  private int quantity;
  private int orderId;
  private int[] clerksId;
  private String name;
  private String description;
  private String dateOfOrder;
  private String note;
  private BigDecimal price;

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public int getProductId() {
    return productId;
  }

  public void setProductId(int productId) {
    this.productId = productId;
  }

  public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
  }

  public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
  }

  public int getOrderId() {
    return orderId;
  }

  public void setOrderId(int orderId) {
    this.orderId = orderId;
  }

  public int[] getClerksId() {
    return clerksId;
  }

  public void setClerksId(int[] clerksId) {
    this.clerksId = clerksId;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }

  public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
  }

  public String getDateOfOrder() {
    return dateOfOrder;
  }

  public void setDateOfOrder(String dateOfOrder) {
    this.dateOfOrder = dateOfOrder;
  }

  public String getNote() {
    return note;
  }

  public void setNote(String note) {
    this.note = note;
  }

  public BigDecimal getPrice() {
    return price;
  }

  public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
    this.price = price;
  }
}
```

### my_json.json

```
[
  {
    "id" : 103,
    "productId" : 6,
    "quantity" : 1,
    "orderId" : 10195,
    "clerksId" : [ 1, 2, 6 ],
    "name" : "keyboard",
    "description" : "-",
    "dateOfOrder" : "2021-02-08",
    "note" : "",
    "price" : 62.2
  }
]
```

### Test.java

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<MyObj> list = objectMapper.readValue(Test.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("my_json.json"), new TypeReference<List<MyObj>>() {});
    System.out.println(list);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your JSON file content seems to be a String & is not a true JSON representation.

Comment: I will edit my comment to add the method I created for creating my json file, take a look.

Comment: Did you try objectMapper.writeValue(Paths.get(filePath.toString()).toFile(), listToParse Ref. https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#writeValue(java.io.File,%20java.lang.Object)

Comment: Right, I was blind before eyes and did not see I was passing the string to the writeValue, thumbs up